# brew install apache-spark error: tar: copyfile unpack (spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/.../SUCCESS.crc) failed: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, apache-spark, homebrew

When trying to install Apache Spark using homebrew on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10, I get a strange error as shown below:

```
$ brew install apache-spark
==> Downloading https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=spark/spark-1.5.0/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.
==> Best Mirror http://mirror.nexcess.net/apache/spark/spark-1.5.0/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
######################################################################## 100.0%
tar: copyfile unpack (spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned/SUCCESS.crc) failed: No such file or directory
  /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.0: 621 files, 304M, built in 3.4 minutes
```

Anyone else encountered this error before?

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this?